# draw line in chart

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

I need to draw a line on the chart as this link: http://astro.unl.edu/naap/hr/animations/hrExplorer.html    (the line is in "red").

See my code: http://jsfiddle.net/tmDpZ/20/

But I do not know how to draw the line in red in the chart.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are simply missing a color option for data1 in your call to plot()

```
function plotSlide(data2) {
    console.log('cross val is '+data2[0][0]+','+data2[0][1]);
    $.plot($("#chart1"), [{
        data: data1,
+       color: 'red'},
    {
```

Comment: This function is drawing the cross in the chart. I want to draw the line(red) between points 10^5 - 10^-3. Like this: http://astro.unl.edu/naap/hr/animations/hrExplorer.html

See my code: http://jsfiddle.net/tmDpZ/20/

Do you understand?